# Check if a column exist or not

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When I try to check if the column exist or not it crushes the app with this error :

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: perfumes (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM savedproducts WHERE pid = 1 AND ptype = perfumes
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1438)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1377)
at app.botikaty.com.DatabaseHandler.CheckIfExist(DatabaseHandler.java:137)
at app.botikaty.com.ViewProductActivity.onCreate(ViewProductActivity.java:80)
```

And what I've tried is this code (DatabaseHandler.java:137) :

```
 int CheckIfExist(String id,String type) {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE pid = " + id + " AND ptype = " + type;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

ViewProductActivity.java:80

```
int issaved = dbHandler.CheckIfExist(theproductid,theproducttype);
            if (issaved != -1){
                savebtn.setLiked(true);
            }else{
                savebtn.setLiked(false);
            }
```

I wish the problem is clear and understandable , what to do please ?

Some files I've used :

DatabaseHandler.java -> https://pastebin.com/94pkJFLd

Contact.java -> https://pastebin.com/P8DiHbxY

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change it to this:

```
 String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE pid = " + id + " AND ptype = '" + type+"'";
```

this just puts single quotes around your type string to signify that it is a string value to the database

So the query will look like this:
SELECT * FROM savedproducts WHERE pid = 1 AND ptype = 'perfumes'

The difference is ptype = perfumes vs ptype = 'perfumes' in the actual query

You weren't putting the single quotes around your type string, so the database thought that you were trying to get a column when it was you actually trying to tell it a value for ptype